Simple QisKit circuit seems to return incorrect statevector?
I have below a very simple circuit that initializes 2 qubits, and then saves the statevector.  I cannot figure out why the simulator returns a vector of all 0's for the statevector. I'm using an older version of Qiskit (version 0.29.1) intentionally, but I would still expect the output to be correct.
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit 
from qiskit.quantum_info import Statevector 
Bell_3_sv = Statevector([0.000, 1.00/np.sqrt(2), 1.00/np.sqrt(2), 0.00]) 
qc = QuantumCircuit(2) 
qc.initialize(Bell_3_sv)
qc.save_statevector() 
print(qc.draw('text'))  
sim = Aer.get_backend('statevector_simulator') 
result = execute(qc, backend=sim).result() 
sv1 = result.get_statevector(qc) 
print(sv1) 

yields
[0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j]
I've seen many other similar questions, and some of them point to the following common mistakes:

not calling measure_all when getting counts (which doesn't even apply here).
not calling save_statevector
forgetting that the least significant qubit should be last

I don't believe that any of these common mistakes apply, so what is the expected output?
EDIT:
!pip list | grep qiskit yields
!pip list | grep qiskit
qiskit                    0.29.1
qiskit-aer                0.8.2
qiskit-aqua               0.9.5
qiskit-ibmq-provider      0.16.0
qiskit-ignis              0.6.0
qiskit-terra              0.18.2


What happens if instead of using qc.initialize(Bell_3_sv) you use gates to get the state: qc.h(0) + qc.cx(0,1) + qc.x(0) ? Does it generate the same all-zeros vector? The earliest ver of qiskit I was successfully able to install was 0.35, so there's no way to test your code.

What's your qiskit-terra version? More generally, what is the output of qiskit.__qiskit_version__?

@diemilio, thanks for your continued interest in this problem.
I tried
qc = QuantumCircuit(2) 
qc.x(1)
qc.h(0)
qc.cx(0,1)

and it STILL produces an all 0's vector.

@TristanNemoz, versions have been edited into the question

I can't reproduce the problem. My qiskit version is:
>>> import qiskit
>>> qiskit.__qiskit_version__
{'qiskit-terra': '0.18.2', 'qiskit-aer': '0.8.2', 'qiskit-ignis': '0.6.0', 'qiskit-ibmq-provider': '0.16.0', 'qiskit-aqua': '0.9.5', 'qiskit': '0.29.1', 'qiskit-nature': None, 'qiskit-finance': None, 'qiskit-optimization': None, 'qiskit-machine-learning': None}

And the following code, filling in the missing imports:
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit 
from qiskit.quantum_info import Statevector
import numpy as np
from qiskit.providers.aer import AerProvider
from qiskit import execute
Bell_3_sv = Statevector([0.000, 1.00/np.sqrt(2), 1.00/np.sqrt(2), 0.00]) 
qc = QuantumCircuit(2) 
qc.initialize(Bell_3_sv)
qc.save_statevector() 
print(qc.draw('text'))  
sim = AerProvider().get_backend('statevector_simulator') 
result = execute(qc, backend=sim).result() 
sv1 = result.get_statevector(qc) 
print(sv1) 

prints:
     ┌──────────────────────────────────┐ ░ 
q_0: ┤0                                 ├─░─
     │  Initialize(0,0.70711,0.70711,0) │ ░ 
q_1: ┤1                                 ├─░─
     └──────────────────────────────────┘ ░ 
[0.        +0.j 0.70710678+0.j 0.70710678+0.j 0.        +0.j]


Strange that it gives you a different result.  Just in case - what's your python version?  I'm using 3.9

@makansij I think I used Python 3.9 but can't confirm it right now, sorry. Did you try your code on a different virtual environment?

No, I haven't.  May I ask why you suggest to do that?  I'm not sure how it would help .

@makansij Just to try to identify where the problem might come from. In that case, whether the problem still happens when you run the code in a fresh environement
