What are expected counts for simple circuit with CNOT gate?
I admit that this should be a simple question, but somehow I'm still struggling with it.
I have the following circuit in qiskit:
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, execute, Aer, assemble, QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister

qc = QuantumCircuit(2)
qc.x(0)
qc.h(0)
qc.cx(0,1)
qc.measure_all()
print(qc.draw(output="text"))

sim = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
result = sim.run(qc).result()
counts=result.get_counts()

And as an exercise I wanted to work out the math to see what the resulting statevector should be.  However, I'm getting something unexpected for both 1). the statevector, and 2). the counts.  I'm hoping someone can help me understand why.
Firstly, when I work out the math, I get the following resulting statevector:
The circuit operating on the input state $|00>$ can be represented by these operations:
$$(|0 \rangle \langle 0| \otimes I + |1 \rangle \langle 1| \otimes X)(I \otimes HX)|00 \rangle$$.
Now, when I work out the math I get the following result:
$$(|0 \rangle \langle 0| \otimes I + |1 \rangle \langle 1| \otimes X)|0 \rangle |- \rangle$$
$$\frac{|00 \rangle - | 01 \rangle}{\sqrt{2}}$$
So the final result that I get is:
$$|0\rangle \otimes |-\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (|00\rangle - |01\rangle)$$
However, this disagrees with both the circuit counts, and also the statevector printed by qiskit:
print(counts)
{'11': 516, '00': 508}

...And the statevector printed (after adding qc.save_statevector() and other necessary modifications to the code above):
array([0.70710678-8.65956056e-17j, 0.70710678-8.65956056e-17j,
       0.70710678-8.65956056e-17j, 0.70710678-8.65956056e-17j])

This doesn't make sense to me since the statevector is not normalized to 1.  Nor does it match the math that I worked out above.
It is important to note that I'm using qiskit version 0.29.1.  Can someone please help me identify what I'm doing wrong?  Thank you.

In your qiskit code, you are applying the $CX$ gate with the control in the least-significant qubit (q0) and the target in the most-significant qubit (q1).
So, to match your circuit, the definition of the $CX_{q_t q_c}$ gate should be:
$$CX_{q_1 q_0} = (I \otimes |0 \rangle \langle 0| + X \otimes |1 \rangle \langle 1|)$$
EDIT:
Here is what you end up with assuming your qubit ordering is given as $|q\rangle = |q_1\rangle \otimes |q_0\rangle $ which is in line with qiskit's ordering:
$$
\begin{aligned}
|q\rangle &= (I \otimes |0 \rangle \langle 0| + X \otimes |1 \rangle \langle 1|)(I \otimes HX)|0\rangle \otimes |0 \rangle 
\\
\\
|q\rangle &= (I \otimes |0 \rangle \langle 0| + X \otimes |1 \rangle \langle 1|)|0\rangle \otimes |- \rangle
\\
\\
|q\rangle &= (I \otimes |0 \rangle \langle 0| + X \otimes |1 \rangle \langle 1|)|0\rangle \otimes \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0 \rangle - |1 \rangle)
\\
\\
|q\rangle &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle \otimes |0 \rangle \langle 0|(|0 \rangle - |1 \rangle) + |1\rangle \otimes |1 \rangle \langle 1|(|0 \rangle - |1 \rangle))
\\
\\
|q\rangle &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle \otimes |0 \rangle - |1\rangle \otimes |1 \rangle)
\\
\\
\end{aligned}
$$
Now, if you run the following code (same as what you have just for the latest version of qiskit), the results agree with this derivation:
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator
from qiskit.quantum_info import Statevector

qc = QuantumCircuit(2)
qc.x(0)
qc.h(0)
qc.cx(0,1)
print(Statevector(qc))
qc.measure_all()
print(qc.draw(output="text"))

result = AerSimulator().run(qc).result()
counts = result.get_counts()
print(counts)

Statevector([ 0.70710678+0.j,  0.        +0.j,  0.        +0.j,
             -0.70710678+0.j],
            dims=(2, 2))
                  ┌───┐ ░    ┌─┐
   q_1: ──────────┤ X ├─░────┤M├
        ┌───┐┌───┐└─┬─┘ ░ ┌─┐└╥┘
   q_0: ┤ X ├┤ H ├──■───░─┤M├─╫─
        └───┘└───┘      ░ └╥┘ ║ 
meas: 2/═══════════════════╩══╩═
                           0  1 
{'00': 506, '11': 518}


Thanks for pointing that out, and sorry for missing that.  However that doesn't explain why the statevector is not normalized to 1, does it?

The only thing you need to change to match your qiskit circuit is the definition of the CX gate. I edited the answer to make it clearer. Not sure why you are getting that statevector. Hard to tell since you did not provide the code for how you get that array.

https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/39963/

Something seems to be wrong with this version of qiskit.

Maybe use the Statevector class (like in my code) instead of the AerSimulator get_statevector method you linked to. Even in the older version you are using I think Statevector will give you the correct result.
